# Unconverted Data Remains after Format

Tags: python-3.x, strptime

I've had a look at the other questions relating to strptime and Unconverted Data Remain, but struggling to see where I am going wrong within the code.

```
            currentTime = format(currentTime, '%H:%M:%S')
            #remove the current time from phone time
            timeDifferenceValue = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(currentTime), FMS) - datetime.datetime.strptime(
                str(ptime) + ":00", FMS)
            else:
                time_left = time_left[-7:]
                time_leftHatch = datetime.datetime.strptime(time_left, FMS) - timeDifferenceValue
                time_leftHatch = format(time_leftHatch, '%H:%M:%S')
```

The error was being found at this stage:

```
                                        time_leftHatch = datetime.datetime.strptime(time_left, FMS) - timeDifferenceValue
```

The values of timeleft and timeDifference Value are:

time_left = 1:29:47
timeDifferenceValue = 0:13:31

The Error:
unconverted data remains: :47

John in the comments mentioned I should change remove the excessive use of strptime when it is unneccessary. This seems to have resolve the Unconverted Data Remains.

For example, timeDifferenceValue was already in the format of time, so this didn't need changed at all.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can simplify your code down to a single `strptime` which fails.  Please do that, and post the input string and format string, with no extraneous other code.

Comment: Hi John, Thanks for the comment. Sorry, I am fairly new to Python, but I'm not too sure what you mean by making it become a single strptime. Almost all the values within the code are actually strings (excluding one I think - which I have now removed the strptime from). By removing this strptime, it seems to have fixed this issue. I don't understand how unfortunately though as I assumed that it would be converting due to the FMS. I'll remove any unneccessary code at the moment. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate problem is this:

```
datetime.datetime.strptime("0:"+str(time_left), FMS)
```

I'm not sure why you're prepending "0:" but that results in "0:1:29:47" for which your strptime format only parses the first three values. The "unconverted data" error is letting you know that there's some extra information in your input string that the format string isn't handling.

The better fix, though, is to stop stringifying and strptiming which will continue to cause you grief. You already have some hints of using `timedelta` in your code. Taking the difference between times in Python returns a timedelta, and adding a timedelta to a time returns a new time. Doing it this way keeps you in structured data and well-defined results.

For example,

```
# do this early, don't go back to string
phone_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(ptime + ':00', FMS)

# and leave this a datetime instead of stringifying it later
currentTime = datetime.datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=1)

# now you can just take the difference
timeDifferenceValue = currentTime - ptime
```

And:

```
if str(timeDifferenceValue).__contains__("-"):
```

becomes

```
if timeDifferenceValue < timedelta(0):
```

Hope that gets you pointed in the right direction!

Comment: Hi Aron, Thank you very much for this explanation. You're absolutely spot on with the "0:". I actually removed this in the end. Initially, the reason why this was in place is because I was using AWS Image Recognition, and it was pulling the phone time from the screenshot, and then deducting from the current time. This meant I had to add a 0: at the beginning. However, this shouldn't be an issue any more as by default, it will go to 01:XX:XX if required.

Comment: Great! I added a bit more about datetime and timedelta. Hope that helps. Welcome to Python!